# Apache Wicket Repeaters: an overview

Tags: java, wicket

Wicket has many implementations of AbstractRepeaters: ListView, DataView, GridView, Loop, PropertyListView etc.

Personally, I find it hard to determine which view would be ideal for which scenario. I usually stick to DataView but that's simply because I'm used to it. Maybe GridView would be better for scenario A, a PropertyListView for B, ....

Is anyone aware of a blog or any tutorial where the differences of the views are explained or anyone who can explain which view is best for which use case?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Wicket has a lot of additional, trivial classes, which is causing your confusion.  Different components *are* better for different scenarios, but there are a lot of Wicket components for rare cases that don't add any real complexity.

For example, `RequiredTextField` is an entire class that is equivalent to:

```
 TextField x = new TextField("text");
 x.setRequired(true);
```

I presume this stems from an older version where setting required was more complicated, but it's still there to cause some confusion.

Many of your repeaters are similar.  `PropertyListView` just wraps the model in a `CompoundPropertyModel`, making property expressions easier (see below).  However, you could easily make this change yourself.

So, here is my quick summary as I have been unable to find an up-to-date blog post as you've described:

**RepeatingView** - very useful when you do not have a list or you are adding different types of components (and therefore different internal markup).

**ListView** - useful if you have a `List` and you're displaying the whole thing.  Sadly, it does not work with other sorted collections.

**DataView** - useful if you are loading from a Database.  Additional methods allow you to easily sort, page, and modify the data set.

**PropertyListView** - useful if you are simply displaying values via a property expression.  Allows you to do

```
 item.add(new Label("name"));
```

instead of

```
 item.add(new Label("name", new PropertyModel<String>(item.getModel(), "name")))
```

**Loop** - useful if you want to repeat an `Integer` number of times instead of a set list of data.  This would be equivalent to a `ListView` whose model object is a `List<Integer>` filled with integers from `0` to `length`

**GridView** - useful for taking a single list (e.g. 21 strings) and using two sets of markup (inner/outer) to display that list in groups (e.g. a 7x3 grid).  It assumes, however, that your markup uses certain wicket:id's, which is not well documented.  I think you would be better off with a pair of nested `RepeatingView` components, which accomplish the same thing.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, this will help indeed :-).

Comment: Another nice overview https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Tables+and+Grids